# Why trivial copyable class require the destructor must be trivial

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Base on the C++ standard. The **trivial copyable class** are define as following:

According to 9/5,

```
A trivially copyable class is a class that:
- has no non-trivial copy constructors (12.8),
- has no non-trivial move constructors (12.8),
- has no non-trivial copy assignment operators (13.5.3, 12.8),
- has no non-trivial move assignment operators (13.5.3, 12.8), and
- has a trivial destructor (12.4).
```

By my understanding, the **trivially copyable class** is which can be copied by bitwise copied.
So what's the intuition and reason to require **trivial destructor** which is unrelated to the bitwise copy.

Comment: At least one point is `virtual destructor`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is simple enough. Trivially copyable means that it is valid and defined behaviour to copy one object A over the top of another B. Obviously the destructor for B will not be called, so it has to be trivial.

There is a description of object lifetime at N3797 3.8/4 which appears to cover the situation. However, there could be a loophole regarding reuse of storage and non-calling of non-trivial destructor provided the program does not depend on side effects of the destructor.

Answer (score 1):

A non trivial destructor likely implies you are deleting some pointers.
If this is the case it seems error prone to do a bitwise copy of the class since you'd then have two instances that will both try to delete the same pointer.

This is just a guess though

Comment: But you can also delete it in other member function instead of destructor after bitwise copy. Require non trivial destructor doesn't resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the C++ object model, a type which satisfies the concept of Trivially Copyable is logically one who's data is just a block of bits. The type is just a collection of fundamental data objects with some value(s). As such, copying a block of bits to some storage is a perfectly valid operation, and that storage should (if appropriately aligned) now contain such an object. Furthermore, it's perfectly reasonable to copy a block of bits to some temporary storage (regardless of alignment) and then copy it back into an object of the appropriate type.

C++ allows all of this for Trivially Copyable types.

If a type really is just a block of bits... why should its destruction involve anything more than just memory deallocation? Or more importantly, if its destruction does need to do more than deallocate memory, is it *really* just a block of bits?

C++'s answer is no, it is not. Or rather, we cannot *prove* that it isn't just a block of bits.

That's the thing about Trivial Copyability rules: it's all about proof. Under trivial copyability rules, we can *prove* that such a type is just a block of bits. Other types *might* be blocks of bits, depending on what those functions do. But since we cannot prove whether they are or not, we therefore forbid treating them as such.

Comment: Does destruction require memory deallocation at all? I thought it merely precedes it in many cases.